# interfacing spartan 3 fpga with arduino motor shield

Tags: dc-motor, spartan

I am doing a project on spartan 3 xc3s200 series. I have already programmed it to run a counter. I want to run a dc motor using the same fpga. And I have a motor driver -Ardiuno motor shield(L298P) and I need to connect the motor to this driver as i cannot connect it directly to fpga. But I am not able to find how do I connect my ardiuno board to the spartan board.
i request for some help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You connect the driver to the Spartan however you like. The L298P is a dual H-Bridge device and has the following block diagram:

[image]

Without the exact motor board you are using it is hard to say how it will be wired exactly, but so long as you control the logic states of the pins on this device then you will be good to go. All the power necessary to drive the motor will come from Vs shown above, not the Spartan.

You must concern yourself only insofar as to drive the logic state of the pins in an appropriate manner to get the desired behavior.

[image]